# React Hook useMemo has an unnecessary dependency: 'match'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

this my code

```
const Head: FC<{ match: faceMatch<{}> }> = ({ match }) => {
  const [arrProd, setArrProd] = useState<JSX.Element[]>([]);
  const [ImgCatIndx, setImgCatIndx] = useState<number>(0);
  const [resError, setResError] = useState<string>("");
  useMemo(() => {
    setImgCatIndx(0);
```

> ```
>  }, [match]);//warning React Hook useMemo has an unnecessary dependency
> ```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const abortController = new AbortController();
    const signal = abortController.signal;
    document.title = `Hat Jacket Pants Shoes Suit | Amasia`;
    (async () => {
      setArrProd([]);
      setResError("");
      try {
        const Res = await fetch(
          `https://foo0022.firebaseio.com/New/${headcateg[ImgCatIndx]}.json`,
          {
            signal: signal
          }
        );
        if (!Res.ok) {
          throw new Error("Page Not Found 404");
        }
        const ResObj = await Res.json();
        const ResArr = await Object.values(ResObj).flat();
        await setArrProd(
          ResArr.map(
            ({
              to,
              id,
              price,
              src,
              title,
              sold,
              shipping
            }: faceProductList) => (
              <Fragment key={id}>
                <NavLink to={to}>
                  <img
                    src={`/${src[0]}`}
                    alt={title}
                    height={"220px"}
                    width={"220px"}
                  />
                  <span>{price}</span>
                  <span>{shipping}</span>
                  <span>{sold}</span>
                </NavLink>
              </Fragment>
            )
          )
        );
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.name !== "AbortError") {
          setResError(error.message);
        }
      }
    })();
    return () => {
      abortController.abort();
    };
  }, [ImgCatIndx]);

  if (resError !== "") {
    return <HandlerErr error={resError} />;
  } else if (!arrProd.length) {
    return <Loding />;
  }
return(....)
```

I get in the console.

> React Hook useMemo has an unnecessary dependency: 'match'. Either exclude it >or remove the dependency array.

I want When changing the match has changed and ImgCatIndx = 0.it's not clear why I'm getting a warning here..How can this be related..How to fix the warning?

Answer (score 0):

You should use useEffect instead of useMemo.If you use the react router, then the match object changes when history is updated, even when passing the same parameters and correctly transmit the parameters themselves.